# Spring 3.2 forward request with new object

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to forward a request from one controller to another controller and set a object in request so that the forwarded controller can use it in @RequestBody.

Following is the exact scenario:

Twilio calls a controller method with data sent by client as following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sms", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String receiveSms(@RequestParam("Twiml") String twiml, 
    HttpServletRequest request, 
    HttpServletResponse response) {

    //TODO - Create new instance of Activity and populate it with data sent from client
return "forward:/activity/new";
}
```

Now, I want to forward this request to ActivityController which already handles the request from web/rest clients.
ActivityController.java has a method with following signature:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/activity/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Activity> updateLocation(
    @RequestBody Activity activity) {

}
```

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the object and add it to the request as an attribute in the first controller,

```
request.setAttribute("object",new OwnObject()),
return "forward:/activity/new";
```

In the updateLocation Method retrieve that object from the request

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/activity/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Activity> updateLocation(
    @RequestBody Activity activity, HttpServletRequest request) {
   OwnObject o = (OwnObject) request.getAttribute("object");
}
```

Comment: Twilio sends an XML request which contains the user sent data. I want to create an object of Activity object using those parameters and then forward it so that it gets available to method in ActivityController.java

Comment: You can add the Activity Object as a @RequestBody Object and it will map the xml to the object then add it to the request and forward it to  updateLocation.

Comment: public String receiveSms(@RequestBody Activity activity, HttpServletRequest request, 
    HttpServletResponse response){}

Comment: Since forward sends exactly the same call to all the handlers I think that creating the Activity Object and adding it as an attribute to the request will be reflected on the request received in updateLocation.

Comment: That worked, just need to mark Activity in ActivityController to required = false [@RequestBody(required = false)]